# Re-sampling based on dependent variable value in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has a dependent variable (1 or 0) and around 650 features. The distribution of dependent variable values (1 and 0) is 1:8 in favor of 0. So when running a classification algorithm, I need to do class weighting or do resampling from the less available class to factor into account the class weight thing. I know re-sampling also introduces a bias as you are duplicating certain records in the data but thats the two approach I know as of now for class imbalance problem in machine learning.

```
model_data1.readmission.value_counts()
Out[23]:
0    81718
1    11275
dtype: int64
```

So what I need is out of 90K odd observations, I want to at least have 70-80K observations in the end with almost equal distribution of 0 and 1 unlike what I have now as shown above. So it would require basically re-sampling from 11K odd 1 observations to increase the size of 1 observations in the data.

How to do this is postgres sql

Answer (score 0):

How about just taking all the 0s and then duplicate the 1s until there are equal numbers?

```
with counts as (
      select sum(case when dep = 0 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dep0,
             sum(case when dep = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as dep1
      from t
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by dep order by random()) as seqnum, dep0
      from t cross join
           (select generate_series(1, ceiling(dep1 / dep0)
            from counts
           ) c
     ) t
where seqnum <= dep0;
```

Comment: I need to duplicate the records. Like I am re-sampling a row of the dataset where the dependent variable is 1. I think what your code is doing is it is duplicating 1's but what about the values of 650 features I have corresponding to 1's?

Comment: @Manish . . . This code should result in an equal number of 0s and 1s.